# Write a program to replace the following list of key phrases with underscore in between them in given text:

Tags: python

```
list_of_keyphrases = ['Prince Charles', 'Prince William', 'Meghan Markle', 'United Kingdom', 'North America', 'Duke and Duchess of Sussex', 'Queen Elizabeth II']

text = 'On January 8, Prince Harry and Meghan Markle, the Duke and Duchess of Sussex, unveiled their controversial plan to walk away from royal roles. We intend to step back as ‘senior’ members of the royal family and work to become financially independent while continuing to fully support her majesty the queen, they said in a joint statement. We now plan to balance our time between the United Kingdom and North America, continuing to honor our duty to the Queen, the commonwealth and our patronages. This geographic balance will enable us to raise our son with an appreciation for the royal tradition into which he was born, while also providing our family with the space to focus on the next chapter, including the launch of our new charitable entity, the statement added. Apparently, the announcement on the Sussex Royal Instagram page blindsided the Queen and other family members who had no idea it was coming, it sent tabloids into overdrive. Meanwhile, the Queen summoned Senior Royals to an emergency summit to discuss the future of the Duke and Duchess of Sussex. Billed as the Sandringham summit, the meeting took place at the Queen's estate in Norfolk and involved Queen Elizabeth II, Harry his father, Prince Charles and his brother Prince William, with Meghan Markle reportedly joining the Discussions by phone from Canada. Soon after, the queen released a statement, that said, My family and I are entirely supportive of Harry and Meghan Markle desire to create a new life as a young family. Although we would have preferred them to remain full-time working members of the Royal family, we respect and understand their wish to live a more independent life as a family while remaining a valued part of my family.'
```

```
import re
for i in list_of_keyphrases:
    if i in text:
        text=text.replace(i,"_")
        
print(text)
```

Output:

```
On January 8, Prince Harry and _, the _,unveiled their controversial plan to walk away from royal roles. We intend to step back as‘senior’ members of the royal family and work to become financially independent whilecontinuing to fully support her majesty the queen, they said in a joint statement. We nowplan to balance our time between the _ and _, continuing tohonor our duty to the Queen, the commonwealth and our patronages. This geographicbalance will enable us to raise our son with an appreciation for the royal tradition into whichhe was born, while also providing our family with the space to focus on the next chapter,including the launch of our new charitable entity, the statement added. Apparently, theannouncement on the Sussex Royal Instagram page blindsided the Queen and other familymembers who had no idea it was coming, it sent tabloids into overdrive. Meanwhile, theQueen summoned Senior Royals to an emergency summit to discuss the future of the Dukeand Duchess of Sussex. Billed as the Sandringham summit, the meeting took place at theQueen's estate in Norfolk and involved _, Harry his father, _and his brother _, with _ reportedly joining the discussions byphone from Canada. Soon after, the queen released a statement, that said, My family and Iare entirely supportive of Harry and _ desire to create a new life as a youngfamily. Although we would have preferred them to remain full-time working members ofthe Royal family, we respect and understand their wish to live a more independent life as afamily while remaining a valued part of my family.
```

I want output with names of the list which are present in the string to be replaced with underscores...

Answer (score 0):

You imported regular expressions library but never used.

re.sub() function lets you change strings the way you want in this question.

re.sub(substringYouAreWannaChange,ConvertedTo,OriginalText)
You can use regular expressions for the first parameter but in this case you can use this.

```
for i in list_of_keyphrases:
    text = re.sub(i, "_", text)
        
print(text)
```

will probably work. Output goes like this:

> On January 8, Prince Harry and _, the _, unveiled their controversial
> plan to walk away from royal roles. We...

However, if you don't want to use re library you can simply use replace method.

in this case change to:

```
for i in list_of_keyphrases:
    text = text.replace(i,"_")
```